# Videos not autoplaying on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, video

I'm using reactjs and for some reason, videos are not autoplaying on mobile.
I'm using iOS 17, Safari
Here is my code:

```
<div className="video" ref={videoRef} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                    __html: `
                <video 
                loop 
                muted 
                autoplay 
                playsinline 
                muted 
                defaultMuted 
                loop
                >
                 <source src=${video} type="video/mp4" />
                  </video>
        `}}>
```

On mobile, there is just a play button.

I also tried to play the video using javascript:

```
const videoRef = useRef(null)
    useEffect(() => {
        if (videoRef.current) {
            const videoElement = videoRef.current.children[0];
            videoElement.play();
        }
    })
```

However, I get the error: `The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission =.```

**Edit: How I solved this issue**:

*Reason for the error*: When on Low Power mode, Auto-play videos is off on Safari By Default

*How I fixed it*: If the video was not displaying, Simply we can add a postor attribute to video, which'll bring a play button for it to start playing, However, I used a img tag if video wasn't autoplaying as there is a play button then. Here is my code:

```
    const [videoPlayed, setVideoPlayed] = useState(false)
    useEffect(() => {
        if (videoRef.current) {
            const videoElement = videoRef.current.children[0];
            videoElement.play().then(() => {
                setVideoPlayed(true)
            }).catch(err => {            })


                document.addEventListener("click", () => {
                        videoElement.play().then(() => setVideoPlayed(true)).catch(() => {})
                    document.removeEventListener("click", () => {})
                })
        }

return (
        <>
                {/* If video isn't played */}
                <div className="image">
                    {!videoPlayed && <img src={thumbnail} alt="Alt" />}
                </div>
                <div className="video" ref={videoRef} style={{
                    display: videoPlayed ? "block" : "none"
                }} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                    __html: `
                <video 
                loop 
                muted 
                autoplay 
                playsinline 
                muted 
                defaultMuted 
                loop
                poster="${thumbnail}"  
                >
                 <source src=${video}  type="video/mp4" alt="content" />
                  </video>
        `}}>
                </div>
)
```

In the above code, There'll be a placeholder image. If the video is able to autoplay, then video will be start playing. In some cases, the video still isn't played, also there is no error, So to fix that, I've added a event listener for `click`, which'll play the video.

Thanks @DarshShah, @JaromandaX, @MohamdImran For helping me solving this issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autoplay policies on mobile browsers, especially Safari on iOS, can be quite challenging due to user experience and data consumption considerations. To address this, browsers typically require user interaction before allowing autoplay.
you're facing this issue due to autoplay is not allowed without user interaction on mobile devices. The attempt to play the video using JavaScript won't work unless a user interaction event triggered .so `play` method should be triggered in response to a user interaction, like a button click or so , something like

```
const handlePlay = () => {
  const videoElement = videoRef.current.children[0];
  videoElement.play();
};


<button onClick={handlePlay}>Play My Video</button>
```

another solution would be using the `playsinline` attribute due to Safari on iOS has a requirement that videos must be played inline. make sure that you included  this attribute in your video tag

```
  <video
  loop
  muted
  autoPlay
  playsInline
  defaultMuted
  loop>
  <source src={video} type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Another solation if above didn't work for anyone , we can try to play the video component mounted via `useEffect` hook by passing an Empty dependency array to ensure that it runs only once on mount also I've combined timeout func to come around the browser restriction especially on mobile devices  , I'll will explain Now  By delaying the `play()` method with a timeout, you like creating a small window after the initial render during which the `play()` method is called. This is essentially simulating user interaction, allowing the video to start playing.

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

const VideoPlayer = ({ video }) => {
  const videoRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const playVideo = () => {
      if (videoRef.current) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          videoRef.current.play().catch(error => console.error('Autoplay error:', error));
        }, 500); // Adjust the delay as needed
      }
    };

    // Play the video on page load
    playVideo();
  }, []); // Empty dependency array ensures the effect runs only once on mount

  return (
    <div>
      <video ref={videoRef} loop muted playsInline defaultMuted>
        <source src={video} type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
    </div>
  );
};

export default VideoPlayer;
```

Comment: I tried using playsinline, but it doesn't work

Comment: @1dk - did you read the part of the answer before that? .. *autoplay is not allowed without user interaction on mobile devices*

Comment: @JaromandaX I've added it as an example

Comment: @MohamdImran - I was responding to 1dk :p Your answer is perfectly fine, just clearly the OP didn't read it

Comment: @JaromandaX Oh , didn't notice my bad .Thanks

Comment: Autoplay works without any user interaction.
You would not be able to autoplay video on iOS if your battery saver mode is on.

Comment: @DarshShah, Thanks, This was the Exact reason for this  issue

Answer (score 1):

In Some mobile devices, `autoplay` is only allowed if the video is triggered by a user interaction, such as a tap. Therefore, you can use a button or other UI element to start the video. Further, you can align its CSS class `display:none` So there is no button visible.

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';

const AutoPlayVideoWithButton = () => {
  const videoRef = useRef(null);

  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    videoRef.current.play();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <video ref={videoRef} playsInline>
        <source src="your-video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>
      <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>Play Video</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AutoPlayVideoWithButton;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just click on the autoplay option that is showing in youtube..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).